# Get time plotted data to automatically line up in correct date order regardless of blank cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a set of data points plotted over time.  Time is plotted monthly and the results for Suplhate (example given) are plotted quarterly. Results are entered in the same month every quarter for each series.  Some months sulphate results are unavailable and are left blank.  the blanks cause a problem, skewing the data to the left - i.e. if a result is missing in January the next March result is plotted alongside the other series' January results etc.

The example below shows BH28 skewed to the left.  The data points should in fact begin in 2011 and not 2006.  How do I correct this.

In other instances where this has happened I have input a dash [-] which correctly aligns the data points but enters a zero value.  I have also tried [=na()] which doesn't solve my problem.

BH28 data points should be towards right hand side of graph instead of left
[image]

Data is time plotted in columns from left to right.  It is common for there to be empty cells in the series (i.e. no sample).

[image]

Comment: please share also how is your source data organized.

Comment: Máté, data is time plotted in columns from left to right. It is common for there to be empty cells in the series.

Comment: Máté's point is that, if we see what the data looks like, we can figure out why it is not being plotted as expected, and maybe we can suggest alternative ways to indicate things like missing data.

Comment: I have updated to include a screen grab of the data.  I realise it might not be the best layout however it is an historic setup and would take quite a bit of time to undo.  Regarding missing data, I mean missing input data (i.e. there will be a blank cell for that month).  This sometimes means the graph reads it as blank and falsely skews the graphical data to the left rather than leaving a blank, despite the date columns matching.

Comment: In the "select data source" form of chart you have a button `Hidden and empty cells` there you can select how Excel should manage missing values, have you checked that?